# How to use byte array convert to binary image( 0bits,1bits )?

Tags: java, image, binary

I want to transfer my bytearray into a binary image
But I don't how to do it.
array value only have 0 and 1.

0 = black , 1 = white,

```
byte [] arr = new byte[32*32];
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  arr[i]= i%2==0?(byte)0:(byte)1
}
```

please help me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are going to do with that binary image.
If you only need it for your computation, your array may do the job for you better,
although a 2-dimensional array may be more convenient to use.

If you want to construct a BufferedImage object, you can specify it to be
1-bit per pixel type (see below), and fill its content using the setRGB() method.
Such image can then be saved to file or shown in GUI, or accessed with getRGB() method.

Here is a working example (GenerateChecker.java):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class GenerateChecker
{

    private static final int width = 32;
    private static final int height = 32;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
            BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

            int white = (255 << 16) | (255 << 8) | 255;
            int black = 0;

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                            im.setRGB(x, y, (((x + y)&1) == 0) ? black : white);

            File outputfile = new File("checker.png");
            ImageIO.write(im, "png", outputfile);
    }
}
```

~

Comment: sorry,I can't understand this line(under)
Can you explain it ,thanks
"int white = (255 << 16) | (255 << 8) | 255;"

Comment: it's just to build the completely white color - where the red=255 (bits 23-16), green=255 (bits 15-8), and blue=255 (bits 7-0).

the description of  java.awt.BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY ( [link]https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_BINARY ) says that in case of 1-bit image, the color model allows only two colors - 0,0,0 and 255,255,255.